# trying to implement dynamic increase of max on android seekbar

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I'm implementing a seekbar that allows users to set a price.
I want the seekbar to start out with a max of 100, then if the user moves the seekbar all the way up to 100, the max goes up to 250 and if the user moves the seekbar all the way up to 250 it goes up to 500, finally stopping at 500+ if the user moves the seekbar all the way up to 500.

The code that I've written works, for the most part. The problem is that when the user moves the seekbar up to the max, since the user is holding their finger there, android thinks that it's constantly at the max so it just instantly increases to 500+, so I need to find a way to disable touch after increasing the max until the user lifts their finger.

So...I want to break the user's touch from the seekbar so that it waits until the next NEW touch event so that this won't happen. If anyone knows a way to do this, please let me know asap!! thanks!

What I've already tried is disable and reanabling the seekbar when it reaches the max, in hopes of breaking the touch, but this doesn't work.

The code I have is below:

```
private class PriceChangeListener implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

    private TextView priceView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_price_label);
    private TextView maxPriceView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_price_max_label);
    private boolean increaseMax;

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        String textToSet = "About how much will it cost? $" + String.valueOf(progress);
        if(progress < 500)
            priceView.setText(textToSet);
        else
            priceView.setText(textToSet + "+");


        if(progress == seekBar.getMax() && increaseMax) {
            seekBar.setEnabled(false);
            switch (progress) {
                case 100:
                    seekBar.setMax(250);
                    increaseMax = false;
                    maxPriceView.setText("$" + String.valueOf(seekBar.getMax()));
                    break;
                case 250:
                    seekBar.setMax(500);
                    increaseMax = false;
                    maxPriceView.setText("$" + String.valueOf(seekBar.getMax()));
                    break;
                case 500:
                    maxPriceView.setText("$500+");
                    break;
            }
            seekBar.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        increaseMax = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: What about a boolean that you set true on onStartTrackingTouch(), and false when the seeker hits a max? and if the boolean is false, you don't increase the max

Comment: @howdoidothis good thinking, this fixes the setting of the values, but the progress bar still stays where the user last held their finger, it really needs to break the touch completely to be a viable implementation

Comment: Really? Nice!! What do you mean that it stays there? So when the user reaches 100, which is the max, the max is set to 250, but since the bar was at the max, does it just stay on the spot that is 250 now? is that what you mean, if so, try manually setting the value, e.g. to 100 right after you call setMax(250)

Comment: @howdoidothis What happens is when you move the seekbar up to 100, it changes the max to 250 and the seekbar stays on the same position (which is now 250, since your finger is still there long enough for android to think it's been moved there again). What it needs to do is drop back to the new position of 100 on the seekbar and stay there until the user moves it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further improving my comment, give this a shot

```
private boolean newTouch = false;
private int oldProgress;
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
if (fromUser) {
    if (newTouch) {
        oldProgress = progress;
        priceView.setText("About how much will it cost? $" + String.valueOf(progress));
        if(progress == seekBar.getMax()) {
            newTouch = false;
            switch (progress) {
                case 100:
                    seekBar.setMax(250);
                    seekBar.setProgress(100);  
                    maxPriceView.setText("$" + String.valueOf(seekBar.getMax()));
                    break;
                case 250:
                    seekBar.setMax(500);
                    seekBar.setProgress(250);
                    maxPriceView.setText("$" + String.valueOf(seekBar.getMax()));
                    break;
                case 500:
                    seekBar.setProgress(250);
                    maxPriceView.setText("$500+");
                    break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        seekBar.setProgress(oldProgress);
    }
}
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    newTouch = true;
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully. although you forgot to add in the line where you set oldProgress to current progress :) I added that in right below the check for newTouch. thanks a ton

Comment: While you were cooking this up, I tried using a runnable in a new thread that disables, sleeps, then reenables the seekbar to allow time for the user to let go - lol. When it woke up and renabled the seek bar, it just moved up to the max progress again

Comment: Haha nice! I'm glad it did!